# How do I submit "POST" method forms in Django without AJAX?

Tags: python, django, forms, post, csrf

I'm completely new to Django and I'm also developing a very important project in this framework with some friends. I'm having problems in submitting a **"POST"** method form in Django.

I'm having the `"403 Forbidden" error`. It says that my `CSRF token isn't configured correctly`. I'm pretty sure that I did setup it correctly, though.
My form is about updating an django user account in the database (MySQL). I also don't know if my program logic is right in the view. I didn't even had the opportunity to test it because of this dumb error.
The image and codes below exemplificate my problem.

My form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/validacao/" name="user" class="current2"> {% csrf_token %}

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nome:</td><td>
            <input type='text' name='first_name' maxlength='30' value='{{usuario.first_name}}' class="campo2" />
            </td> 
            <td>Permissão: <font style="color: red;">
            {% if usuario.is_staff %} Admin {% else %} Comum {% endif %}</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sobrenome:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='last_name' maxlength='30' value='{{usuario.last_name}}' class="campo2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email' maxlength='75' value='{{usuario.email}}' class="campo2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Senha:</td><td> <input type='password' name='password' maxlength='120' class="campo2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Confirmar Senha:</td><td><input type='password' name='password2' maxlength='120' class="campo2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='salvar' value='Salvar' class="botao2"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

My view:

```
def validacao_perfil(request):

    if request.POST:

        try:
            request.user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            request.user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
            request.user.email = request.POST['email']
            request.user.password = request.POST['password']
            request.user.save()
            validacao=1
        except:
            validacao=0

    variaveis_resposta={  'usuario':request.user,
                          'MEDIA_URL':settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          'height_backgroud':'900',
                          'rodape':'position:relative; top: 148px;',
                          'ordem':0,
                          'validacao':validacao,
                          'context_instance':RequestContext(request),
                          }

    return render_to_response("perfil_usuario.html", variaveis_resposta)
```

Obs.: the "urls.py" is set correctly and the bizarre thing is that I can see the csrftoken cookie var using Django Debug Toolbar.

Comment: Still, what about your settings.py? Do you have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` enabled?

Comment: Adding to Alex: do you see csrf token in rendered html?

Answer (score -1):

just put @csrf_exempt on your `def validacao_perfil(request):`, to see if this work,and also try to read the doc of django .It's very good!!

Comment: I highly doubt topic owner wants his code to work "anyhow", there's still a problem to be solved.

Comment: Does @csrf_exempt disables CSRF verification? I just want to make it work well with CSRF enabled, but I didn't had luck with that.
I got a way to disable this CSRF thing, but I think it's important to have it working for this project.